# Regular expression - check if its the pattern at the end of string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings like this:

```
something-12230789577
```

and I need to extract digits that end with a question mark symbol or **NOTHING** (which means the found pattern is at the end of the string)
Match here should be: '12230789577'
I wrote:

```
r'\d+[?|/|]'
```

but it returns no results in this example. \s works for space symbol, but here I'm met with an empty symbol so \s is not needed.
How can I add the empty symbol (end of string) to the regex condition?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
re.search(r'\d+[?]?$', t)
```

where:

- `t` is the text input
- `[]` checks for a character
- `?` checks for 0 or 1 occurrence.

Edit:

- `$` checks for end of string.

Comment: it will also match: -325- but it shouldn't.

Comment: `re.search(r'\d+[?]?$', t)` this might work. `$` checks for end of string

Answer (score 0):

Keeping ?|/ symbols optional(0 or 1).

```
import re
a='something-A12230789577'
b=re.search(r'\d+[?|/]?',a)
b
```

Comment: this also matches: something-A12230789577X but it shouldn't.

Comment: you can put a word boundary at the end if you don't want the string that has something after the last digit. b=re.search(r'\d+[?|/]?\b',a).

Symbols "? , / , |" if they exist it will still be considered. You can remove the symbols inside the [ ] that you don't want.

Comment: You can also use b=re.search(r'\d+[?]?$',a) If digits are the end of the string that you want to extract.

Comment: re.search(r'\d+[?]?$',a) -- this almost works, but for string that has more characters after '?' it doesn't work. For example: -5555?abaabab

Comment: I dont understand your question, so do you want to match the string -5555?abaabab and get only the digits as output?

Answer (score 0):

I've came to the solution. It searches for the sequence of digits that start with '-' symbol and end with: **?** or **/** or **nothing**.

```
(?<=-)\d+(?=>\?|[?]|\?|$)
```

so in Python:

```
re.search(r'-(\d+)(?:[?|/].*)?$', text)
```

test example:

something-37238?somerandomstuff900

outputs: 37238